# Subdomain DNS seems to only be partially propagating

Tags: dns, bind, propagation, bind9

I own a domain, and clearly its DNS resolution is fine, everywhere seems to point to the right server : https://dnschecker.org/#A/e-bis.fr

I created a wildcard for subdomains, and it seems like it only points to the right server in some random places in the world, changes randomly every once in a while (as in sometimes a server will say it resolves, and one hour later it won't anymore) : https://dnschecker.org/#A/whatever.e-bis.fr

At first I thought it was a propagation issue, but it's been a week now so clearly it's me messing up the config at some point.

Here's the zone file used by bind9 for this domain :

```
@    IN         SOA    ns3032550.ip-91-121-79.eu. postmaster.e-bis.fr. (
     2014070501 ; Serial
     8H         ; Refresh
     30M        ; Retry
     4W         ; Expire
     8H         ; Minimum TTL
)

               IN    NS    ns3032550.ip-91-121-79.eu.
               IN    NS    ns.kimsufi.com.
e-bis.fr.      IN    A     91.121.79.161
*.e-bis.fr.    IN    A     91.121.79.161
ownercheck     IN    TXT   "28834a04"
```

I do a `service bind9 reload` every time I update it, so the only thing I can see is the issue being in the zone file. I'm terrible with them, so it wouldn't surprise me if it was a beginner mistake.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help,
Éric B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had just forgotten to update the serial (I think?).

For anyone running into the same problem, it was this line `2014070501 ; Serial` which I had not updated. Incrementing it then restarting the service is enough.